# Wordwrap on Text inside rectangle will not wrap using Qt QML

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlcomponent

So I have been trying for weeks to simply get my text to wrap when it gets to to end of the rectangle. I have tried loads of things and this snippet is just the latest.
Even if I use Layout ONLY and drop the "anchor" it does not do word wrapping, instead the text looks like the width is not set. Even if I force the rectangle and text width it just gets ignored.

```
var elem = '
    import QtQuick 2.15
    import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

    RowLayout {
        id: rowlayout
        //anchors.fill: parent
        Layout.minimumHeight: 100
        Layout.preferredHeight: 100
        Layout.maximumHeight: 100
        spacing: 6
        Rectangle {
            id: element_one_rect
            color: "'+active+'"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.minimumWidth: root.width * 0.25
            Layout.preferredWidth: root.width * 0.25
            Layout.maximumWidth: root.width * 0.25
            Layout.minimumHeight: 100
            Layout.margins: 10
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "'+description+'"
                color: "'+color+'"
                font.weight: Font.DemiBold
            }
        }
        Rectangle {
            color: "'+active+'"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.minimumWidth: root.width * 0.72
            Layout.preferredWidth: root.width * 0.72
            Layout.preferredHeight: 100
            Layout.margins: 10
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "'+data+'"
                color: "'+color+'"
                font.weight: Font.Bold
                //wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere
            }
        }
    }';
```

Comment: Why should it be incorrect? https://github.com/qt/qtdeclarative/blob/dev/src/quick/items/qquicktext_p.h#L105

Answer (score 1):

I would not expect the Text element to wrap without knowing its fixed size. So adding something like `width: parent.width` to your text element should make it wrap.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as @LucaCarlon also indicated is that `width` has not been set. To demonstrate, look at the following minimal test:

```
    Rectangle {
        width: 250
        height: 250
        color: "grey"
        Text {
            text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\n"
            //width: 100
            //width: 200
            //width: 300
            //width: parent.width
            //wrapMode: Text.Wrap
            //wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            //wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere
        }
    }
```

If you enable any of the `wrapMode` above but do not provide a `width`, you will observe the `wrapMode` is ignored. This makes sense because whilst it is willing to wrap, it doesn't know what to wrap to. Then, when you enable any of the `width` choices, you will suddenly observe that the word wrap will start working for you. Based on how your example reads, it seems that you are needing `width: parent.width`. This was also the conclusion that @LucaCarlon came to quite early on.

You can [Try a demo online](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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).

I also did a review of your code and came up with additional recommendations:

1. Your code appears to be from a snippet that does code injection

   - I highly recommend against that, because it introduces security and performance problems
2. Avoid using complex formula for Layout widths and heights

   - It's better to allow it to size things for you
   - If you use `Layout.fillWidth` with `Layout.preferredWidth` the `RowLayout` will allocate ratioed spacing for your components
3. As per @GrecKo's suggestion of using `Label` instead of `Text` so you can use `background` and `padding` to stylize a frame and avoid unnecessary pixel calculations
4. Also as per @GrecKo's suggestion use `Text.Wrap` which achieves a balance between `Text.WordWrap` and `Text.WrapAnywhere`

Here's a demonstration of the above:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Page {
    property string txt: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\n"
    property color activeColor: "green"
    property color textColor: "white"
    RowLayout {
        id: rowlayout
        width: parent.width
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        Label {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 200
            background: Rectangle { color: activeColor }
            padding: 10
            text: txt
            color: textColor
            font.weight: Font.DemiBold
            wrapMode: Text.Wrap
        }
        Label {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 400
            background: Rectangle { color: activeColor }
            padding: 10
            width: parent.width
            text: txt
            color: textColor
            font.weight: Font.Bold
            //wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            //wrapMode: Text.WrapAnywhere
            wrapMode: Text.Wrap
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Your original answer consisted of two points: one was from my answer, which preceded yours of hours, the second was simply wrong and I had already provided the Qt code to show it. Now you removed the errors, but the critical point remains the one I provided. A downvote seems reasonable to me, sorry.

Comment: @LucaCarlon you also edited your answer. In your original answer, you expressed you had not tried it. Because of that comment, I actually hadn't read the details of your answer. I investigated my own answer. Whilst it may appear to be a derivated of yours, it was not. I went about it on my own and by coincidence realize it overlapped yours afterward. When I realized it, I took measures to credit you.

Comment: @LucaCarlon about my error. I wanted to express a recommendation for Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere over the Text.WrapAnywhere enumerated type. The argument I made was poor, and, hence, opened myself to blunder. However, the intent remains in that I still recommend that enumerated type. My overall intent is to provide a holistic response and I did hope to provide broad constructive feedback even though it may not have been solicited.

Comment: for 3: no need for a `Frame` if you are using `Label`, it already has a `background` and a `padding` property. If you really want to use a container control, `Pane` is less specific than `Frame`
for 4: `Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere` is not documented anymore and was always equivalent to `Text.Wrap`, just use that.

Comment: @GrecKo thanks. I made an edit based on all of your suggestions.